# iOS/Android - TCP/IP over Bluetooth

Tags: android, ios, sockets, bluetooth, tcp

I will briefly describe what I am trying to do and any help will be appreciated.

I have some devices (I will refer to them as 'Devices') (basically sensors) which are connected to some other devices (I will refer to them as 'ConnectDevices') using Ethernet (TCP/IP). These Devices basically send some data values they are monitoring. Th ConnectDevices have two interfaces: Ethernet + Bluetooth (2.1 + EDR) and they are connected to a router and they all form a LAN.

Hence, my question is: is it possible to monitor my Devices (read data) using an iPhone/Android phone? That means I should somehow connect to Devices available on LAN, but thru the Bluetooth interface of (the closest) ConnectDevice. Moreover, it should be possible to connect to any Device from any CoonectDevice even if they are not directly connected.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Impossible to know without documentation / code for how they communicate and the interfaces they expose.

In any case, both TCP and Bluetooth require a specific HOST address to connect to. Without knowing this, the Android/iOS app wouldn't know what to connect to.